# Need help solving an exercise

Tags: javascript

I have a assignment with the following instuctions:[image]

```
let usrInp = 0
const token1 = 1
const token2 = 2
const token5 = 5
const token10 = 10
const token20 = 20
var token1Count = 0
var token2Count = 0
var token5Count = 0
var token10Count = 0
var token20Count = 0
var answer = ""

function input(){
    userInp = prompt("Enter a number between '20' and '100'");
    while(isNaN(userInp) || userInp < 20 || userInp > 100){
        alert("You've entered invalid data")
        userInp = prompt("Enter a number between '20' and '100'")
    }
```

I've figured out a simple `if` statement for some of the even inputs however, I am not sure how to make one function that'll solve all of the inputs

```
if (userInp == 20){
        token20Count = 1
        answer = token20Count + " " + "*" + " " + token20
    }else if (userInp == 30){
        token20Count = 1
        token10Count = 1
        answer = token20Count + " " + "*" + " " + token20 + "," + token10Count + " " + "*" + " " + token10     
    }
    document.write(answer + " " + "tokens makes up the total of" + " " + userInp)

}
window.onload = input
```

Comment: A [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) can solve this problem (at least for given the set of tokens you have been given).  You will find solutions on the net. It's also known as the coin change problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should make an array of all the possible token values rather than have 10 individual standalone variables. Then iterate over the array, from the highest number to the lowest, subtracting as many of that token value as you can from the input on each iteration:

```js
const inputNum = Number(prompt('Num?', 58));
let num = inputNum;
const tokenValues = [20, 10, 5, 2, 1];
const output = tokenValues
  .map((value) => {
    // Figure out the maximum number of `value` that will fit into the `num`
    const count = Math.floor(num / value);
    num -= count * value;
    return `${count} of token ${value}`;
  })
  .join('\n');
console.log(inputNum + ':\n\n' + output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let userInp=53;
function calc(){
    var t1 = Math.floor(userInp/token20);
    userInp= userInp-(t1*token20);
    var t2 = Math.floor(userInp/token10);
    userInp= userInp-(t2*token10);
    var t3 = Math.floor(userInp/token5);
    userInp= userInp-(t3*token5);
    var t4 = Math.floor(userInp/token2);
    userInp= userInp-(t4*token2);
    var t5 = userInp;
    console.log(t1+','+t2+','+t3+','+t4+','+t5);
};
calc();
```

Hope you get the general idea of how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break the problem up into components.

First, the case where we have exactly 1 coin and count of 0-1:

- 0 []
- 1 [1]

no surprises, we just see how the problem composes. We have a collection of coins, a range to consider, and the set of coins minimal to achieve each count.

the case where coins are [2,1] and count is 0-5:

- 0 []
- 1 [1]
- 2 [2]
- 3 [2,1] # and not [1,1,1]
- 4 [2,2]
- 5 [2,2,1]

notice that so far we do good by using a *greedy* approach that just uses the largest coins.

counterexample: Is there a case where that would not be true?

coins: [5,4,2,1] range: (only 8)

- 8 [ 4, 4 ] # not [ 5, 2, 1]

the reason is that 8%5 == 3 and we have a coin between this value and the starting 5, so we have two to consider. 1x5 + minCoins(3) vs 1x4 + minCoins(4).

If the growth in value from coin to coin >= 100% we won't have that problem. In your case:

1-2: 100%
2-5: 150%
5-10: 100%
10-20: 100%

now, we should be satisfied to just exhaust the largest coins.